# How to get the current admin user or userId in an app?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

How can I get the current admin user or his ID at least?

I could not find any approach in the documentation or else where. Is it possible?

Comment: Where and when do you need the id of the user? Within an app script? When a webhook is dispatched?

Comment: @dneustadt I need it when I do an insert into my custom entity, which I have created in my app. So its an API call. I want to know which admin user it was.
Do you have any suggestions on those aproaches?

Comment: @dneustadt so i guess it inst possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I'm aware of but I can't say for sure if it may be possible with use of some trickery which is why I didn't want to answer the question definitely.

Comment: @dneustadt My idea is to extend the Iframe src and send it to the iframe, and on my site i would then remove that property, to verify the hash, or even better to extend the service which builds the properties before there are signed, and add a sw-user-id proberty to it...
But, I dont think there is way to do that from an app? But maybe from a plugin?